# .htaccess file for multple control pages and wildcard subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wildcard

I can't seem to get my head around configuring an .htaccess file that sends to different control pages based on the subdomain, then uses wildcards for user subdomains.

What I need is essentially this:

1. If domain.com, redirect to www.domain.com/index.php
2. If www.domain.com, rewrite to www.domain.com/index.php
3. If img.domain.com, rewrite to www.domain.com/img/
4. If api.domain.com, rewrite to www.domain.com/api/index.php
5. If admin.domain.com, rewrite to www.domain.com/admin/index.php
6. If (anything else).domain.com, rewrite to www.domain.com/users/index.php - also sending the value of the subdomain as a variable.

All of the tutorials I've seen send all requests to a single page which is then routed, I would like the htaccess file to do some of the work beforehand.

Comment: You do understand that on the different subdomain to domain it will do a external redirect and not a internal redirect since they are not the same right? For example in this case `img.domain.com` to `www.domain.com/img/` it will not retain the `img.domain.com` on the browser URL. However if the folder `img` is also accessible to `img.domain.com` and you want to keep it as the URL then you can directly internally redirect to it.

Comment: @Prix How should I do it if I want to keep the subdomains?

Comment: If you type `http://img.domain.com/img/` does it lead to the same folder as `www.domain.com/img/` or they do not share the same `documentroot`?

Comment: img.domain.com and www.domain.com/img are the same folder.

Comment: Then what you want to do makes sense, why would you want to rewrite `img.domain.com` to `www.domain.com/img` if they are the same folder and you wish to retain `img.domain.com` as the URL since that would be what it already does without being rewritten.

Comment: I want the url to remain as img.domain.com/image.jpg.  Is it possible my question should have said redirect instead of rewrite? Since I need to retain all subdomains in the urls.

Comment: In your point 6, what do you mean by `also sending the value of the subdomain as a variable` ? Can you be more explicit ?

Comment: @Justin  I need the router at *.domain.com/users/index.php to be able to determine what specs to load based on the user id. I thought it might be faster if that was sent as a variable by the htaccess file instead of looking at the subdomain with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subdomains are not pointing to same documentroot's main domain (you will have to enable **mod_proxy**)

```
RewriteEngine on

# 1. www-rule: domain.com to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# 2. skip www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

# 3/4/5. manage img, api and admin subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(img|api|admin)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1/$1 [P]

# 6. manage users
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/users/index.php?user=%1 [P]
```

If your subdomains are pointing to same documentroot's main domain (mod_proxy is not needed here)

```
RewriteEngine on

# 1. www-rule: domain.com to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# 2. skip www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

# 3/4/5. manage img, api and admin subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(img|api|admin)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

# 6. manage users
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/index.php?user=%1 [L]
```

---

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine on

# 1. www-rule: redirect domain.com to www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# 2. www.domain.com rewritten to index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# 3. img.domain.com rewritten to img folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /img/$1 [L]

# 4/5. api or admin subdomains rewritten to /api/index.php or /admin/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(api|admin)\. [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1/index.php [L]

# 6. manage users
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule . /users/index.php?user=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I copied the second version into my htaccess file, replaced domain with localhost for testing. I got an Internal Server Error on all except www.

Comment: It is hard to test it with localhost because you will have to add wildcard subdomains on local environment. Instead, can you test it in production with your domain name ?

Comment: In #2 and #3/4/5 I need all requests to all subdomains (except img) to go to a controller page. 'www.domain.com/index.php' and 'www.domain.com/admin/index.php'.

Comment: And what about `img` subdomain ? I'm a little surprised by what you asked because it's far away from your original question

Comment: The img subdomain doesn't need to be passed to a controller, it's just a folder of images. My question states that I wanted the redirects to be to separate control pages, though that could be more clear if I had added 'index.php' to each of the list items.